# Exercise in population dynamics

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling, biology

> Consider the single species population model defined by
>
> $$\frac{dR}{dt} = \frac{gR}{R+R_m} - dR,$$
>
> for $t > 0$, where $g,R_m$, and $d$ are all positive parameters and $R(0) =R_0$.
>
> (a) Describe the biological meaning of each term in the equation.
>
> (b) Determine the steady-states of the system and discuss any constraints on the model parameters for the model to admit biologically meaningful solutions.
>
> (c) Determine the steady-state stability and discuss any variation in this with respect to the model parameter values.

---

=>
a) $gR$ represents the exponential growth of population, $dR$ represents the exponential decay of population, $g$ is the growth rate, and $d$ is the decay rate. What do $R$ and $R_m$ represent? How can I define the term $$\frac{gR}{R+R_m}?$$
What is $R+R_m$? Does it affect the $gR$ for the grow?

b) In single steady-state system, $$\frac{dR}{dt} =0.$$
$$\frac{gR}{R+R_m} - dR = 0$$
$$ gR -dR(R+R_m) =0 $$
$$ R(g -d(R+R_m)) =0$$
either $R=0$ or $g -d(R+R_m)= 0$.
$$g- dR_m =0    \ \ \ (R=0)$$
$$R_m = \frac{g}{d}$$
$$R^{\ast} = \frac{g}{d} \ \ \  (R_m = R^{\ast})$$
So, we have $R^{ast}_1 = 0$, $R^{\ast}_2 = \frac{g}{d}$
Are these correct? I am not sure constraint on the model parameters to admit biologically meaning solutions?

c)
to determine steady-state stability
let $$f(R) =\frac{gR}{R+R_m} - dR $$
$$\frac{df}{dR} = g ln(R+R_m) -d . $$
My differentiation may be wrong and don't know the term $R_m$ while differentiating with respect to $R$.
I really don't know after that. and I know my answer is still incomplete.

Comment: How can the terms $\frac{dR}{dt}$ and $dR$ have the same dimensions and thus be equated?

Answer (score 1):

$R_m$ is a constant.  Your computation of the steady states doesn't look correct. $R=0$ is one steady state, and solving $g - d(R + R_m) = 0$ for $R$ will give you the other.  When computing $\frac{df}{dR}$, you should use the quotient rule.  Again, $R_m$ is a constant so its derivative is zero.